# Trying to stream audio data from a hackRF (using gnuradio) to a web server and have a client select the frequency they want to listen to

Tags: python, audio, server, streaming, gnuradio

I am trying to stream audio data from a hackRF (using Linux, gnuradio) to a web server and have a client select the frequency they want to listen to.
However, I would like to explore better options. Right now, I am thinking there is a way to either use GNURadio's built in UDP, TCP or XMLRPC blocks to do this without a wav file. That would be the best option as far as I know.
The second option is to continue with the wav files although this is straining on CPU and memory. I want to be able to play these files as they are being captured.

Please let me know if there is a preferred option or a technique that I have not mentioned.

I have a server up and running and am currently using a .wav file that is captured at a given frequency, and uploaded and played from a server. I can do this with multiple frequencies. The end goal is to have multiple users select a frequency to listen to on an app and stream it.
All of the SDR front end components are able to pick up signals and produce audio. It is getting it to the server that is complicated.

Comment: This is a cool project and I hope you'll continue pursuing it but your question is way too broad as-is.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78035713/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.